# Multi-Vendor Help desk

Tags: help-desk

I have been working with a lot of clients world wide and at one point of time their business needs a help desk software.

I wanted to know if there is any solution that includes a multi-vendor help desk solution? I want to install the helpdesk solution on one server and provide licenses to use the software to my clients.

Basically a zendesk or freshdesk opensource edition where I can define the pricing model for my vendors.